# Using cufft when operating with the thrust library

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I want to combine the `thrust` library and `cufft` in my project. Thus for testing I wrote

```
    int length = 5;
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double> > V1(length);
    thrust::device_vector<cuDoubleComplex> V2(length);
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double> > V3(length);
    thrust::sequence(V1.begin(), V1.end(), 1);
    thrust::sequence(V2.begin(), V2.end(), 2);
    thrust::transform(V1.begin(), V1.end(), V2.begin(), V3.begin(), thrust::multiplies<thrust::complex<double> >());
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, length, thrust::complex<double>, 1);
    cufftExecZ2Z(plan, &V1, &V2, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        std::cout << V1[i] << ' ' << V2[i] << ' ' << V3[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    return  EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Unfortunately, `cufft` only accepts arrays such as `cuDoubleComplex *a`, while `thrust::sequence` is only working properly with `thrust::complex<double>`-vectors. When compiling the code above, I get two errors:

```
error : no operator "=" matches these operands
error : no operator "<<" matches these operands
```

The first one refers to `thrust::sequence(V2.begin(), V2.end(), 2);`, while the second one refers to `std::cout << V1[i] << ' ' << V2[i] << ' ' << V3[i] << '\n';`. If I comment `V2`, everything works fine.
Is there a conversion between `thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double>>` and `cuDoubleComplex *`? If not, how can I combine them?

Comment: how about using `thrust::tabulate` with a custom `UnaryOperation` instead of `thrust::sequence`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`thrust::complex<double>` and `std::complex<double>` share the same *data layout* with `cuDoubleComplex`. As a result, all that is required to make your example above work is to cast the data in your `device_vector` to raw pointers and pass them to cuFFT. Thrust itself can't work with `cuDoubleComplex` in most operations because that type is a simple container which doesn't define any of the operators which are required to perform any of the operations which Thrust expects for [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) types.

This should work:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cufft.h>

int main()
{
    int length = 5;
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double> > V1(length);
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double> > V2(length);
    thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double> > V3(length);
    thrust::sequence(V1.begin(), V1.end(), 1);
    thrust::sequence(V2.begin(), V2.end(), 2);
    thrust::transform(V1.begin(), V1.end(), V2.begin(), V3.begin(), 
                         thrust::multiplies<thrust::complex<double> >());
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, length, CUFFT_Z2Z, 1);
    cuDoubleComplex* _V1 = (cuDoubleComplex*)thrust::raw_pointer_cast(V1.data());
    cuDoubleComplex* _V2 = (cuDoubleComplex*)thrust::raw_pointer_cast(V2.data());

    cufftExecZ2Z(plan, _V1, _V2, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        std::cout << V1[i] << ' ' << V2[i] << ' ' << V3[i] << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    return  EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: CUFFT_C2C -> CUFFT_Z2Z